# Find & Replace String in All Found Files with LaTeX $sim$ -> $\sim$

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I know this sort of question has been asked many times before, but I'm running into an odd circumstance where my feeble brain forgot to include a `\` while calling `$\sim$` in some markdown files. I need to go through and replace all instances of `$sim$` with `$\sim$`. My code is running but not actually replacing any of the words that I want. Here are some variations I have tried:

```
grep -rl '\$sim\$' . | xargs sed -i 's/\$sim\$/$\sim$/g'

grep -rlF '$sim$' . | xargs sed -i 's/\$sim\$/$\sim$/g'

grep -rlF '$sim$' . | xargs sed -i 's/$sim$/$\sim$/g'

grep -rlF '$sim$' . | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/$sim$/$\sim$/g'
```

And other odd variations on a theme. The code just runs with no output but when I check the files nothing has changed. I figure this is either a `sed` issue (I'm macOS) or a regex issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
grep -rlF '$sim$' | xargs sed -i 's/$sim\$/$\\sim$/g'
```

for MacOsX :

```
grep -rlF '$sim$' | xargs sed -i '' 's/$sim\$/$\\sim$/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i` changes files in place, however you aren't telling sed to operate on any files. You are giving sed its input on stdin.

What you want is something like

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\$sim\$/$\\sim\$/g' {} \;
```

Comment: OP want to replace only files with `$sim$` in it, and seems to use MacOsX. Replacing a files with no match is not good by experience

Comment: The assertion 'you aren't telling sed to operate on any file' is false, OP use xargs

Comment: Oh, you're right about the xargs. grep just wasn't outputting anything for me.  If you are worried about replacing files with no match, using `grep -Fq` as part of the exec statement to make sure there is at least one match.